# Why can `lsof -i` not show an open connection which `netstat -n` lists?

Tags: networking, netstat, lsof, altlinux

A strange situation. I started

```
telnet 0 8081
```

and `lsof -i` (run under root) doesn't list this connection, but `netstat -n` does.

Why can this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just simulated your scenario and was able to get 8081 in both netstat and lsof. lsof -i displays **8081** as **tproxy** and so your grep might not be finding it. Try this with -P which shows the numerical ports:

```
lsof -i -P | grep 8081
```

Comment: Aha! -P: This option inhibits the conversion of port numbers to port names for network files.